# Angular 2 : get image from a static storage using express js

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am using node js with express in the backend side , I have a static folder that contains some images , so I am trying to load those images  with angular 2 in the client side , Here is a part of my code :

backend side:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/Images')); //'./Images' contains images that I need
```

frontend :

```
<mg src="http://localhost:3000/Images/image1.png" /> //it's a fruitlessly try
```

And this is the shown error :

> image1.png:1 GET localhost:3000/Images/image1.png 404 (Not Found) –

Comment: And what doesn't work? You don't see the image?

Comment: @alexmac this is the error : image1.png:1 GET http://localhost:3000/Images/image1.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Not sure, but does `case sensitivity` matters here, would suggest you to change `images` to `/images`

Answer (score 0):

The way I load my images is like below:

```
   <div class="chromecast">
      <img class="img-responsive" 
        src="/images/chromecast-site.jpeg" [style.width]="imageWidth" 
        height="auto">
   </div>
```

I ignore

```
"http://localhost:3000
```

My server.ts is below

```
// Point static path to dist
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

and may be you may have to modify yours:

[image]